# Maven Build hangs between Surefire Tests

Tags: java, mysql, maven, maven-surefire-plugin

For no apparent reason, and without any relevant changes to the code, my DB surefire tests are hanging after a specific test.
The console output indicates that test 50 completes successfully and that test 51 has not yet started

```
[INFO] Running xxxx.server.db.dao.Test50
[INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.954 s - in xxxx.server.db.dao.Test50
```

I've run the following command to retrieve the thread dump below

```
mvndebug -DforkCount=0 clean install
```

The following does not function either and causes the same behavour at the same point in the test run

```
mvn clean install
```

The tests are being run on Windows 10 with a MySQL 5.7 Server using maven 3.3.9. I've tried using different versions of maven without success. Furthermore, I have tried different versions of the surefire plugin and different fork settings, with the only workable combination below

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.21.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <forkMode>always</forkMode>
                <forkCount>1</forkCount>
                <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
                <threadCount>1</threadCount>
                <parallel>suites</parallel>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

The thread dump state at hang time is as follows:

```
    "main@1" prio=5 tid=0x1 nid=NA waiting
    java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:-1)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.awaitDone(FutureTask.java:429)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.awaitResultsDone(ForkStarter.java:460)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.runSuitesForkPerTestSet(ForkStarter.java:441)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:293)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:245)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1149)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:978)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:854)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-1)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)


    "Thread-17@5301" daemon prio=5 tid=0x37 nid=NA runnable
    java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(FileInputStream.java:-1)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:255)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:284)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
    - locked <0x14bb> (a java.io.BufferedInputStream)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
    - locked <0x14bc> (a java.io.InputStreamReader)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:161)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:324)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:389)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.shade.org.apache.maven.shared.utils.cli.StreamPumper.run(StreamPumper.java:76)

    "Thread-17@5301" daemon prio=5 tid=0x37 nid=NA runnable
    java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(FileInputStream.java:-1)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:255)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:284)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
    - locked <0x14bb> (a java.io.BufferedInputStream)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
    - locked <0x14bc> (a java.io.InputStreamReader)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:161)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:324)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:389)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.shade.org.apache.maven.shared.utils.cli.StreamPumper.run(StreamPumper.java:76)


    "Thread-18@5300" daemon prio=5 tid=0x38 nid=NA runnable
    java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(FileInputStream.java:-1)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:255)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
    - locked <0x14ba> (a java.io.InputStreamReader)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:161)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:324)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:389)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.shade.org.apache.maven.shared.utils.cli.StreamPumper.run(StreamPumper.java:76)

    "Thread-16@5299" daemon prio=5 tid=0x36 nid=NA waiting
    java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:-1)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.parkAndCheckInterrupt(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:836)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:997)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1304)
    at java.util.concurrent.Semaphore.acquire(Semaphore.java:312)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.lazytestprovider.TestLessInputStream.awaitNextCommand(TestLessInputStream.java:165)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.lazytestprovider.TestLessInputStream.beforeNextCommand(TestLessInputStream.java:136)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.lazytestprovider.AbstractCommandStream.read(AbstractCommandStream.java:100)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.shade.org.apache.maven.shared.utils.cli.StreamFeeder.feed(StreamFeeder.java:123)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.shade.org.apache.maven.shared.utils.cli.StreamFeeder.run(StreamFeeder.java:60)


    "ping-timer-10s@5111" daemon prio=5 tid=0x19 nid=NA waiting
    java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:-1)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2078)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1093)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:809)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1074)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1134)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)


    "timeout-check-timer@5108" daemon prio=5 tid=0x18 nid=NA waiting
    java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:-1)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2078)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1093)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:809)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1074)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1134)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

All 5 Resolver deamons are in the same state

```
    "resolver-5@5058" daemon prio=5 tid=0x17 nid=NA waiting
    java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:-1)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1074)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1134)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

    "ThreadedStreamConsumer@5298" daemon prio=5 tid=0x34 nid=NA waiting
    java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:-1)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
    at java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue.take(ArrayBlockingQueue.java:403)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.output.ThreadedStreamConsumer$Pumper.run(ThreadedStreamConsumer.java:83)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

It always hangs at the same place in the test run.
I've tried cheching and setting the max connections on the DB. There are only 3 connections active at this time and the limit is 151. The thread setting in MySql has a max of 64.

All the application DB connections for test50 are closed in final try blocks.

Disabling test50 causes the same result. I don't know which test is being run next.

There is of course something that I am missing. Any ideas?

Comment: What Java version did you use when it worked and what are you using now?

Comment: Hi Thorbjorn, the java version has not changed and is 1.8.0-151.

Comment: Post the entire thread dump via pastebin.

Comment: rustyx, I've posted the entire thread dump, but am not aware of pastebin

Comment: Have you tried to run the suspicious tests alone ?

Comment: Hi khmarbaise, all tests run alone. The issue is that I'm not sure which test runs next as it is not started. I tried ignoring the other tests in the package, but still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

The issue in the end was an environmental variable setting.
The PATH on my Windows box included **C:\ProgramData\Oracle\javapath**, which is a link to **C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath**. The JAVA_HOME variable was set to my installation of Java under Program files.

C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath only contains 3 files (java.exe, javaw.exe and javaws.exe) of a previous version.

When I changed the path to my bin directory of JAVA_HOME, everything worked after that.